# xamarin.forms android application stuck in deployment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating cross platform app in xamarin.forms.but when i try to deploy it in xamarin android player.its just stuck there..i had found same question but still no proper solution..please help me..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin Android Player has actually been deprecated, it was never fully released and likely has a few bugs.

Try using the built in visual studio emulator instead:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/

Comment: inbuilt emulator gives me error that hiper-v service is not started..and i camt start it because i have virtual mca os instaled in my pc..so i have only option of xamarin android player.

Comment: Ok, is androids own emulator not an option either? It's very slow but doesn't require hyperV.
Have you tried starting Xamarin Android Player in administrator mode, outside of visual studio?

Comment: yes i tried to run that as administarion.and this is very weird issue..sometimes its works sometime not :(